# Cypress intercept not overriding Cypress alias

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I'm doing some testing and I intercept some API calls to the same URL, I do one `beforeEach`, and then another one on the test, but for some reason I does not understand that I changed the alias. I was doing some reading, and the overriding was fixed, but apparently is not?

My code:

```javascript
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit("/");
  cy.intercept(
    {
      method: "GET",
      url: "/customers*",
      hostname: "local.api",
    },
    {
      fixture: "customers.json",
    }
  ).as("customers");
  cy.get("[class^=ant-menu-item]", { multiple: true }).eq(1).click();
  cy.wait("@customers");
});



[
  ["customerName", "ASC", 0],
  ["nextReviewDate", "ASC", 1],
  ["nextReviewType", "ASC", 2],
].forEach(([sortValue, sortOrder, index]) => {
  it(`Sort by direction ${sortOrder} order ${sortValue}`, () => {
    cy.get(".ant-table-column-sorters", { multiple: true }).eq(index).click();
    cy.intercept("GET", "/customers*").as("request");
    cy.wait("@request").then((interception) => {
      cy.wrap(interception.response.statusCode).should("eq", 200);

      cy.wrap(interception.request.url).should(
        "include",
        `https://allica.local.api/customers?page=1&sortBy=${sortValue}&pageSize=5&direction=${sortOrder}`
      );
    });
  });
});
```

The following error:

[image: "No request ever occurred" error]

If there is not overriding, how can overcome this test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intercept is an event listener. It must be set up before the event is triggered

```js
cy.intercept("GET", "/customers*").as("request");
cy.get(".ant-table-column-sorters", { multiple: true }).eq(index).click();
cy.wait("@request").then((interception) => {
  ...
```

Actually, there's no change to the intercept between tests so you can just set it once and wait multiple times

```js
before(() => cy.intercept("GET", "/customers*").as("request"))

[
  ["customerName", "ASC", 0],
  ["nextReviewDate", "ASC", 1],
  ["nextReviewType", "ASC", 2],
].forEach(([sortValue, sortOrder, index]) => {
  it(`Sort by direction ${sortOrder} order ${sortValue}`, () => {
    cy.get(".ant-table-column-sorters").eq(index).click();
    cy.wait("@request").then((interception) => {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just tried and it works. The second approach you mentioned it doesn't work for all the tests. But changing the line of code it does so I'll stick to that one :) thank you